# Average height of top 10%?

Tags: normal-distribution

Given a normal distribution, I know how to find the minimum required to be in the top 10%. (Finding Z, and then using it to find x). But how do you find the average of the top 10%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The median value of the top $10\%$ would just be the same as the minimum required to be in the top $5\%$. But if you want the mean value, that's harder.

To begin with, let's say a random variable $Z$ has the standard normal distribution. The probability that $Z \ge z$ is the area under the bell curve $f_Z(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}$ over the interval $[z,\infty)$.

The average value of $Z$ is the integral of $x f_Z(x)$; if you integrate this over $(-\infty, \infty)$, you just get $0$ by symmetry. We can figure out the average value of $Z$, conditioned on $Z \ge z$, by integrating $x f_Z(x)$ on $[z,\infty)$, except that we should renormalize by dividing by $\Pr[Z \ge z]$. That is,
$$\mathbb E[Z \mid Z \ge z] = \frac{\int_z^\infty x f_Z(x)\,dx}{\Pr[Z \ge z]}.$$ For the standard normal in particular, we have $$\int_z^\infty x f_Z(x)\,dx = \int_z^\infty \frac{x e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2}.$$

So, to figure out the average value of $Z$ over the top $10\%$, we would first compute the value of $z$ such that $\Pr[Z \ge z] = 0.1$, and then find
$$\mathbb E[Z \mid Z \ge z] = \frac{\int_z^\infty x f_Z(x)\,dx}{0.1}  = \frac{10}{\sqrt {2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2}.$$

To do this for an arbitrary normal distribution, we could just find the $z$-score to be in the top $10\%$, do the above calculation to find the mean value $\mu_{10\%} = \frac{10}{\sqrt {2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2}$, and then take $\mu_{10\%} \cdot \sigma + \mu$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ were the mean and standard deviation of the original distribution.